# How do I compute the adjusted debt-to-equity ratio for a Treasury Stock?

Tags: stocks, treasury, debt-to-income-ratio

I want to compute the adjusted debt-to-equity ratio. The formula is simple: ADE ratio = Total Liabilities divided by Total Equity and Treasury Stock. When I look for Treasury Stock for MSFT (https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/MSFT/income-statement), it seems not being provided while it is for KO (https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/KO/income-statement). Is there a way to efficiently compute the Treasury Stock so that I can compute de ADE ratio?

Answer (score 1):

Not all companies must have any treasury stock so just assume 0 if it is not present. You might search for it in official annual report if you have doubts.

Also, notice that in the Coca Cola data, treasury stock is provided as a negative number. I guess you should add treasury stock as a positive number. So that more treasury stock means lower ratio.

Comment: It is wrong to assume to put it to zero. It is written in the cashflow statement (i.e. MSFT) they repurchased their shares and issued some of them as well. There must be a way to compute the Treasury Stock.

Comment: They do not provide the number in their balance sheet. They provide repurchases info in Note 16, maybe there is no other way but to look at past reports and add them up from every Note 16.